# Function Based View returns multiple values for a forms kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-forms

I have a function based view returns an TypeError on passing a kwarg to a form

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'school'
```

This is the form

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, school,*args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['school'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Student.objects.filter(school=school))
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name','student_id','batch','depart','semester')
        widgets = {
            'school':forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'hidden'}),
        }
```

And the view.

```
def add_student(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        s_form = StudentForm(request.POST,school = request.user.school)
        if s_form.is_valid():
            s_form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('add_student')
    else:
        s_form = StudentForm()
    return render(request, 'libman/add_student.html', {'s_form': s_form})
```

Where this have been done???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first parameter of your init method is `school`:

```
def __init__(self, school, *args, **kwargs)
```

It means that if you make a call with:

```
StudentForm(request.POST, school=request.user.school)
```

then both the `request.POST` and the `request.user.school` will be seen as values for the `school` parameter, which makes no sense.

I would advice to rewrite the order of your `__init__` method parameters to:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    school = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Student.objects.none())

    def __init__(self,*args, school, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['school'].queryset = Student.objects.filter(
            school=school)
        )
```

Then the `request.POST` will passed to the `super()` constructor and thus to the `data=…` parameter of the `ModelForm`.